# How to click on the toolbar <dd> element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing test automation and I want to click on  element located in toolbar,I'm using python and selenium. Here is a code of website

```
<dl class="ToolbarDropdown_menu_2wY9X ToolbarDropdown_isHidden_3UaGr" tabindex="0" style="" 
xpath="1"><dt><span class="ToolbarDropdown_title_1NBVn">New</span>
<span class="DropdownArrow_arrowIcon_dDzph DropdownArrow_down_3dlvo"></span>
</dt>
<dd class="ToolbarDropdown_item_nP-_M" style="">Dataset</dd>
<dd class="ToolbarDropdown_item_nP-_M">Project</dd>
</dl>
```

I need to click on  element with text Dataset.

I locate element in this way

```
DATASET_BUTTON = (By.XPATH, '//dd[contains(text(),"Dataset")]')
```

And I want to perform action like that

```
self.driver.find_element(*VideosPageLocator.DATASET_BUTTON).click()
```

And there is no action but in terminal looks like my step has passed. Do you have any idea how to click on element in dropdown?

Comment: I have seen this with applications that use Angular to load the DOM. The click happens successfully but Angular is still loading the DOM and "ignores" the click. Put `time.sleep(3)` before the click. If that works build a custom function to verify the click resulted in the expected changes to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the action is done before DOM has loaded completely.
Try using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

web_driver_wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
element = web_driver_wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//dd[contains(text(),"Dataset")]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: `wait.until` returns the webelement, no need to relocate it.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Dataset** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//dl[starts-with(@class, 'ToolbarDropdown')]//dd[starts-with(@class, 'ToolbarDropdown_item') and text()='Dataset']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```